# What are the decorators in Angular2, for Components and Directives?

Tags: typescript

This question is more about how decorator is, as related to design patterns and inheritance vs composition.

I have seen decorators in Python, and now in Typescript for AngularJS 2.  They look like:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
        <h2>These are the Courses</h2>
        `
})
export class CoursesComponent {

    // ...

}
```

and a decorator looks very similar for a Directive.

As I understood it, we usually use inheritance in the past to "augment" or "expand" our class, by

```
class Dog < Animal     # in Ruby
```

and that's called white-box re-use.  Composition is black-box re-use.

So are the Decorators for Components and Directives really black-box re-use?  That is, to absorb in an object, and treating it as its internal thing, and open up the exact same interface, and now, whatever message is received, do something extra, and then pass the exact same message to the "absorbed object".

So in the above case, is the `CoursesComponent` being the decorator and absorbing the `Component` object?  In a way, it could also be thought of as `CoursesComponent` inheriting from `Component` -- just except that because we use Decorator and is one form of Composition, and therefore is black-box re-use, making it cleaner than inheritance?

Actually, what difference does it make if `Component` has all properties declared as private so that subclasses cannot touch them, and have our custom components inherit from `Component`. Isn't that as clean as using decorators?

Comment: is it really an exact duplicate?  This is more related to how it works and as related to design pattern and inheritance and composition

Comment: I don't think it is related to design pattern, inheritance and composition. It's just metadata added to the class.

Comment: I think by the name "decorator", it probably does mean it is decorator as in Design Patterns by GoF

Comment: No that's something different. It's like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation

Comment: so you are saying in computer science, the word "decorator" has dual meanings... I will check on that...

Comment: There are words in computer science that have even more than two meanings ...

Comment: well I know, but something that is so special and seems so classical meaning another thing... kind of took me by surprise

Comment: See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html

Comment: interesting... seems like the decorators in Python... they are "functional decorators", very similar to the OOP / GoF..., except those are functional... function absorbing function, not object absorbing object